# Overloading var-args

Tags: java, overloading, variadic-functions

Who can explain why first method preferable than second?

I know this rules for overloading (except first of all compiler find appropriate args)

1. widening
2. autoboxing
3. var-args

Code:

```
public class Proba{

    public static void show(Object ... args){
        System.out.println("Object ...");
    }

    public static void show(Integer[] ... args){
        System.out.println("Integer ...");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] array = {3,2,5,1};
        show(array);        
    }
}
```

**Console** : `Object ...`

Comment: You have a var arg of `Integer[]`. So multiple arrays, not multiple integers.

Comment: Var-arg Integer[] ... args can accept Integer[] , why doesn't do that ? I think it's rather obvious than invoke show with Object... params.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis "Multiple" arrays means 0 or more arrays. A single `Integer[]` is acceptable for both `Integer[]...` and `Integer...`---in different roles.

Answer (score 4):

The rules of method resolution in Java require that a match be attempted *without* auto-(un)boxing and variable arity *before* attempting a match *with* those features.  This ensures source compatibility with language versions that predate those features.

The rules for overload resolution are described in the JLS (§15.12.2):

> The process of determining applicability begins by determining the potentially
>   applicable methods (§15.12.2.1).
>
> The remainder of the process is split into three phases, to ensure compatibility with
>   versions of the Java programming language prior to Java SE 5.0. The phases are:
>
> 1. The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution without permitting
>      boxing or unboxing conversion, or the use of variable arity method invocation.
>      If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues
>      to the second phase.
>      This guarantees that any calls that were valid in the Java programming language
>      before Java SE 5.0 are not considered ambiguous as the result of the introduction of
>      variable arity methods, implicit boxing and/or unboxing. However, the declaration of
>      a variable arity method (§8.4.1) can change the method chosen for a given method
>      method invocation expression, because a variable arity method is treated as a fixed
>      arity method in the first phase. For example, declaring m(Object...) in a class which
>      already declares m(Object) causes m(Object) to no longer be chosen for some
>      invocation expressions (such as m(null)), as m(Object[]) is more specific.
> 2. The second phase (§15.12.2.3) performs overload resolution while allowing
>      boxing and unboxing, but still precludes the use of variable arity method
>      invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing
>      continues to the third phase.
>      This ensures that a method is never chosen through variable arity method invocation
>      if it is applicable through fixed arity method invocation.
> 3. The third phase (§15.12.2.4) allows overloading to be combined with variable
>      arity methods, boxing, and unboxing.
>
> Deciding whether a method is applicable will, in the case of generic methods
>   (§8.4.4), require that type arguments be determined. Type arguments may be
>   passed explicitly or implicitly. If they are passed implicitly, they must be inferred
>   (§15.12.2.7) from the types of the argument expressions.
>
> If several applicable methods have been identified during one of the three phases
>   of applicability testing, then the most specific one is chosen, as specified in section
>   §15.12.2.5.

In your example, there are two candidates during Step 1: the method with an `Object[]` parameter, and the method with an `Integer[][]` parameter.  The argument type at your call site is `Integer[]`.  Since `Object[]` is assignable from `Integer[]`, but `Integer[][]` is not, a single applicable method has been found, and overload resolution halts there.  Steps 2 and 3 are never reached in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Mike is correct; there are 3 phases,

15.12.2.2. Phase 1: Identify Matching Arity Methods Applicable by Subtyping

15.12.2.3. Phase 2: Identify Matching Arity Methods Applicable by Method Invocation Conversion

15.12.2.4. Phase 3: Identify Applicable Variable Arity Methods

`show(Object[])` is chosen in the first phase, but `show(Integer[]...)` can only be chosen in the 3rd phase.

If the first method signature is changed to `show(Object[] ... args)`, you'll see the expected result.

If the second method signature is changed to `show(Integer ... args)`, you'll also see the expected result. The method also fits in phase 1, and it is more specific than `show(Object...)`

---

If we have

```
public static void show(Object ... args){
    System.out.println("Object ...");
}

static class IntArray{}

public static void show(IntArray ... args){
    System.out.println("IntArray ...");
}

show(new IntArray());
```

it prints the expected `IntArray ...`. Here `IntArray` is not a subtype of `Object[]`.

---

This is all too confusing. Programmers usually don't know about these phases; they think about all applicable methods and the most specific one among them. It might have been better if the spec does that too.